# Problemas con array_shift de PHP en un script HTML

Tags: php, html, google-chart-api

Tengo un problema que no puedo resolver y espero que me puedan ayudar:

Estoy trabajando en Wordpress con PHP y HTML para extraer datos de un servidor con MYSQL y luego a dichos datos mostrarlos por pantalla en un gráfico gracias a google charts.

Tanto la toma de datos y almacenarlos en un array funciona. Dentro de php realizo un loop corto de 10 vueltas para que me muestre los 10 primeros valores del array:

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
   foreach ($elemento = array_shift($rIN) as $v1){
      echo "$v1--";
   }
}
```

Este código funciona a la perfección y me muestra los 10 primeros valores del array como necesito.

Ahora si, el problema es cuando necesito hacer lo mismo dentro de un script HTML.

```
for(i=0,i<10,i++){
         data.addRow([i,<?php foreach ($elemento = array_shift($rIN) as $v1){echo "$v1";}?>]);
         }
```

En este caso, google charts solo me grafica en todos los valores de x (0,1,2,3..,10) exactamente el primer valor del array solamente, es decir grafica solo una línea recta horizontal.

Si dentro del loop agrego otra línea data.addRow exactamente igual al anterior, me grafica el primero y el segundo valor de esta forma:

[image: -]

En resumen, cada vez que vuelve a empezar el loop es como si nunca hubiese aplicado el array_shift y el array no se modifico nunca.

En google charts (JS con PHP):

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawHour);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDay);
function drawHour() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Hora');
  data.addColumn('number', 'IN');
  data.addColumn('number', 'OUT');
  for (i=0; i<1; i++){
    data.addRow([i,<'?php foreach ($elemento = array_pop($rIN) as $v1){echo "$v1";}?>,<'?php foreach ($out = array_pop($rOUT) as $v2){echo "$v2";}?>]);
```

Comment: podrías reemplazar los insert_php y lo end por las etiquetas correctas ya que así no se entiende el código

Comment: listo! Mejor ahora

Comment: el primer for en la segunda parte del código es de un js?

Comment: claro, el primer for en php y el segundo dentro de un <script> js

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en el order de ejecución de cada lenguaje.

- `PHP` se compila en el servidor (*se ejecuta primero*) y el resultado es devuelto al navegador ('agente que realiza la solucitud').
- El navegador toma ese resultado devuelto por el servidor y ejecuta `JS` (entre otras cosas).

Es decir que, en cada vuelta del `for` de `JS`, los valores impresos por `PHP` ya se encuentran en el documento, y siempre van a ser los mismo.

### Solución:

Podrías generar el código `JS` con `PHP`.

Ejemplo:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Hora');
data.addColumn('number', 'IN');
data.addColumn('number', 'OUT');
<?php
for ($i=0, $i<1, $i++) {

    echo "data.addRow([$i,";
    foreach ($elemento = array_shift($rIN) as $v1) { echo "$v1"; }
    echo ",";
    foreach ($out = array_pop($rOUT) as $v2){echo "$v2";}
    echo "]);";
} ?>
```

Comment: Tiene mucho sentido lo que decís y es razonable porque no funciona pero lamentablemente sigue sin funcionar de esa manera.

function drawBasic() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Velocidad');
      [insert_php]
      for ($i=0, $i<10, $i++) {

             echo "data.addRow([$i,";
             foreach ($elemento = array_shift($rIN) as $v1) {
             echo "$v1";
             }
             echo "]);";
      } [/insert_php]
      
</script>

Comment: No sabía que se iba a escribir asi... Soy nuevo aca... No grafica nada con ese metodo... Apostaba que si podia funcionar..

Comment: @PabloToledo, ¿podrías agregar en tu pregunta como y donde estas incluyendo el `JS` con el código `PHP`?

Comment: listo pero no se porque no puedo escribir bien el codigo...

Comment: @PabloToledo, ¿ese código esta dentro de un archivo `.php`, cierto?

Comment: el codigo de google charts es java script dentro del body de html. Lo unico que es php en el codigo final q escribi es lo que esta dentro del addRow